# deleted django_admin_log and now i can not use the django admin

Tags: python, django, logging, admin

Django Version: 2.0.3
Exception Type: ProgrammingError
Exception Value:
relation "django_admin_log" does not exist
LINE 1: ..."."app_label", "django_content_type"."model" FROM "django_ad...

---

hen i try

```
 './manage.py sqlmigrate admin 0001' or './manage.py sqlmigrate admin 0001'
```

I get:
db1=> manage.py sqlmigrate admin 0001
db1-> \q
(renew_project) renew_project@renew:~/renew$ python manage.py sqlmigrate admin 0001

### BEGIN;

### -- Create model LogEntry

```
CREATE TABLE "django_admin_log" ("id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, "action_time" timestamp with time              zone NOT NULL, "object_id" text NULL, "object_repr" varchar(200) NOT NULL, "action_flag" smallint NOT              NULL CHECK ("action_flag" >= 0), "change_message" text NOT NULL, "content_type_id" integer NULL, "us             er_id" integer NOT NULL);
ALTER TABLE "django_admin_log" ADD CONSTRAINT "django_admin_log_content_type_id_c4bce8eb_fk_django_co             " FOREIGN KEY ("content_type_id") REFERENCES "django_content_type" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERR             ED;
ALTER TABLE "django_admin_log" ADD CONSTRAINT "django_admin_log_user_id_c564eba6_fk_auth_user_id" FOR             EIGN KEY ("user_id") REFERENCES "auth_user" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;
CREATE INDEX "django_admin_log_content_type_id_c4bce8eb" ON "django_admin_log" ("content_type_id");
CREATE INDEX "django_admin_log_user_id_c564eba6" ON "django_admin_log" ("user_id");
COMMIT;
```

but there is no django_admin_table

---

I have --- INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',

---

I use Postgresql

---

I tried all migrations -  in different way - no results

Please, share your ideas - how to deal with it?
Thanks

Comment: `sqlmigrate` just prints out the commands, it does not run them.

Comment: I did python manage.py migrate admin 0001. So - Any advice?

Comment: `python manage.py migrate admin 0001` would only work if no migrations had been run for the admin app before. Deleting your `django_admin_log` table was a really strange thing to do. Getting your databases and migrations back in sync can be very tricky -- if you don't have any important data in the database the easiest fix is to drop the database and rerun all the migrations.

Comment: there is a an answer in stackoverflow that states that !

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the best thing to do is create a brand new project/database and do the migration there.  Then you will have an empty (or mostly empty) django_admin_log table.  You can then reverse engineer the correct "create table" statement and create it yourself in your original database.